# $\int_{0}^{1} x^{n} f(x) \ dx=0$ for all $n$ and $f$ being continuous implies $f=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $\int_{0}^{1} x^{n} f(x) \ dx = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

---

If $f$ is not continuous, give an example where $f(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes this is true -- but what is your question?

Comment: The first part is a standard exercise in showing that $\int_0^1 g = 0 \implies g= 0$ for continuous $g$, you just use contraposition and the definition of continuity to find a $\delta$-ball where $f$ is positive so the integral is positive.

Comment: @KevinZ. What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: example : $f (x)=0$ but $f (1)=1$.

Comment: A continuous function on a compact interval can be uniformly approximated by a polynomial ([Weierstrass approximation theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassApproximationTheorem.html)).

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2332344/function-in-l-2-space-that-is-f-0-almost-everywhere/2332349#2332349 for the same question where $f$ is in $L^2$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $\int_0^1 x^n f(x)\,dx = 0$, then $\int_0^1 p(x)\,f(x)\,dx = 0$ for every polynomial $p(x)$.

For a counterexample: think of an integrable non-negative function $f(x)$ which satisfies $\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx= 0$.

Comment: I don't think that he is trying to prove the statement in block quotes... I think he is looking for a reason why the statement is *not* true for discontinuous $f(x)$.

Comment: @Nilknarf that's what it looks like after the edit, but from the original question it seems as though he was just copying down the entirety of the problem statement. Added something in anyway.

Comment: " it seems as though he was just copying down the entirety of the problem statemen" I agree. Then why post this?